# Git/SVN workspace under Dropbox?

Tags: git, svn, synchronization, dropbox

I've got unlimited Dropbox space and I've decided to put all my data (excluding OS files) under Dropbox.

I've got plenty of GIT/SVN workspaces (hosted remotely).
Would this conflict in any way? 
Do you have any experience with having working git workspaces checked-out under dropbox folder?

Answer (score -1):

In my experience this will give you no real problems.

You should be careful to make sure the files finish syncing down when you first start using it. If your local git or SVN files are not all synced when you start using the tools you will get very unpredictable behaviour.

In general git is much more relaxed when it gets itself into a mess like this. If you accidentally brick an SVN repository you may find the best solution is just to take a back up of the SVN directory and then check it out from the server again.

Comment: I'll try it out. Will accept your answer once this works ;-) Thanks.